# Is there a more elegant way to chop of the leading character after a stream.reduce?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, reduce

Is there a more elegant way to join the elements of a stream, separating each with a "\n", but not starting with "\n", without having to do that substring(1) call as in the following example?

```
    List<String> strings = someList;

    String rval = strings.stream()
            .map(this::someOperation)
            .reduce("", (p1, p2) -> p1 + "\n" + p2);

    if(rval.length() > 0)
    {
        // trim off the leading "\n"
        rval = rval.substring(1);
    }
    return rval;
}
```

Of course I can replace it with an internal loop, but that would lose the obvious functional readability

Comment: It's not just a matter of elegance.  Your code violates the contract for `reduce` because `""` is not an identity for your accumulator function.  `"" + "\n" + "a"` is not equal to `"a"`.  To correctly do this with `reduce` you should use the 1-argument version:  `.reduce( (a,b) -> a + "\n" + b).orElse("")`.  Then you would not need the `substring` step or risk having extra `"\n"` randomly showing up if the stream were parallel.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: Please add that as an answer and I will upvote it, it's important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are specific collectors that deal with strings efficiently. If you look at [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-), you'll see that it is exaclty what you are looking for:

```
String joined = strings.stream()
    .map(this::someOperation)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: Please mark the other answer as correct. It was posted before mine's.

Comment: They came in within a minute of eachother, and yours was more complete so I thought it would be a tad more useful. Odd though, I woulda sworn I checked the time stamp and thought yours was first anyway

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

It will solve your problem, be much more readable, and also way more efficient, by not creating a whole lot of temporary strings and copies.

Comment: Hey, sorry, my answer is the same as yours, and I posted it later! My excuse: I'm on the phone and didn't see you answered first.

Comment: No problem. That happens all the time in concurrent systems.